# windows 10 64bit running with graphics card ; but no graphics card driver installed

Tags: windows-10

I have 23' LCD  monitor. Purchased a new Zebronics H55 Intel chipset mother bord. socket no 1156. have a nvidea GEFORCE 9500 GT 1gb graphics card. OS is Windows 10. When the driver of the graphics card is installed the system starts showing multiple problems. but without the driver it is working ok. The VGA port of the motherboard is not working so I am using the graphics card. I have i7 1st Gen processor.
My question is, 
1> Is it okay to run a system with a graphics card without its driver? or will there be any problem if the driver is not installed?
2>Graphics card is removed and still motherboard vga giving no display. though the motherboard is new (i.e claimed by the seller) can any one give any insight what may be problem is? (according to seller due to old processor motherboard vga is not working. Is it convinceble?
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay to run a system with a graphics card without its driver?

You can generally use a graphics card with drivers provided by the OS (i.e. without an official driver). Whether this is "okay" is probably a matter of circumstance.

> Will there be any problems if the driver is not installed?

There can be, yes. What those problems might be (if any) is almost certainly dependent on the card. As an example, I have a card that runs with generic drivers but on-screen fonts are noticeable blurred without the "official" drivers installed. Your results may vary.